# "end main" directive breaks a MASM Hello World, works fine with "end"?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I was debugging my hello world program, and got frustrated [so I straight up copied and pasted the example from this website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#%22Hello_world!%22_program_for_Windows_in_MASM_style_assembly) into visual studio and ran it.

It worked. I then took an extra thirty minutes trying to find out what the bug was that broke it. Turns out it's the last line. The below code doesn't work, and the only thing that is changed was the `end main` at the end of the file to `end`.

---

So this assembles, but doesn't work, using `end main`

```
; requires /coff switch on 6.15 and earlier versions
.386
.model small,c
.stack 1000h

.data
hello     db "Hello world!",0

.code
    includelib libucrt.lib
    includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
    includelib libcmt.lib
    includelib libvcruntime.lib

extrn printf:near
extrn exit:near

public main
main proc
        push    offset hello
        call    printf
        push    0
        call    exit
main endp

end main
```

but this version does work, using just `end`

```
; requires /coff switch on 6.15 and earlier versions
.386
.model small,c
.stack 1000h

.data
hello     db "Hello world!",0

.code
    includelib libucrt.lib
    includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib
    includelib libcmt.lib
    includelib libvcruntime.lib

extrn printf:near
extrn exit:near

public main
main proc
        push    offset hello
        call    printf
        push    0
        call    exit
main endp

end
```

All I heard was that it was an optional step you can take to tell the program where the code starts. Additionally, why does it even break the program?

Comment: `end main` sets the program entry point to `main`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/end-masm?view=msvc-160, which is probably not what you want: you want the entry point to be the startup code provided by the C library, which takes care of necessary initialization so that functions like `printf` can work properly.

Comment: Perhaps `end main` is overriding the actual process entry point, and that needs to be the CRT startup code for C stdio functions like printf to work?  IDK, I don't use Windows, but if `end main` is like linking a Linux program with `ld -e main` instead of the default `_start` which crt code provides, that would explain it.  (The CRT code calls `main` by name; you don't have to specify anything else for that to happen, if you link it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want "end main" because you don't want your entry point to be main because this is a libc program and you want the C library up and running before main is called.

You aren't writing start.asm yourself; don't set "end main" like you would do with a libc-less assembly program.